On a functional equation of Mahler?
Recently, I was trying to introduce the concept of natural boundaries to a fellow math student, and what greater way to do this than using an example? In particular, I tried to use as an illustration, the series $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{2^{n}}.$$
Contemplating on how to make the example appear as natural as possible I came to define $f$ through a functional equation $$f(g(z))=F(z,f(z)),$$ where the different functions involved obey various assumptions. For the series above the equation reads $$f(z^{2})=f(z)-z.$$ But, as I tried to completely solve the functional equation, I came to the conclusion that such a feat is by no means an easy one. I managed to describe some solutions other than $f$ by trial and error, but a general solution seems to require tedious power series manipulations in the most optimistic cases.
That being said, as I searched for possible publications on the topic, I came across some papers of Mahler describing what would become known later as ``Mahler's method'', and I was amazed to find out that functions satisfying the equation above posses some quite remarkable arithmetic properties, other than serve as easy examples in complex analysis.
The question remains though: What are the solutions $f$ of the functional equation in general, under the assumptions that

$f$ is holomorphic in unit disk
$g$ is defined as holomorphic at least in an annular neighbourhood of the unit circle $S^{1}$ mapping the circle to itself
$F$ being a holomorphic function in both variables

I uploaded this question to math stack but got no answers there. I would like to know if there are any references to the possible solutions of the functional equation in a general setting.
